# HTML elements not overlapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox, z-index

I'm trying to overlap a close button in the top right corner of an image, and have this entire component be wrapped in a div so that I can use JS to replicate it easier. My html structure is as follows (... is for irrelevant info):

```
<div class="thumb-container">
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="pic-container">
            <img class="pic" ... height="128">
            <button class="close-button">X</button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Messenger: Facebook</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my stylesheet is

```
.thumb-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pic-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

From searching other stackoverflow posts, I found that the combination of two positioned elements and differing z-indexes should produce the result I'm looking for, but instead I got this (.thumb element is replicated with JS):

[image: Result of code]

The button is not overlayed in the top right corner of the image.

**Edit**: Here's the codepen:

https://codepen.io/jeanlucthumm/pen/GVRebe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to adjust your `.pic` class so it fills the container with relative positioning. Then you can set the absolutely positioned button and it will look fine.

```css
.thumb-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pic-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 5px;   
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb-container">
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="pic-container">
            <img class="pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <button class="close-button">X</button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Messenger: Facebook</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `position: relative` set on the image container:

```
.pic-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You want the button to overlap the image, but the image doesn't occupy the full width of the container.

[image]

The absolutely-positioned button is placed relative to the container (the shaded area in the image above), not the image.

Make the image occupy the same space as the container, then your button can be placed as desired.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YmzMEb)

Answer (score -1):

use this css for close button in right side

```
.thumb-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .thumb {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .pic-container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .close-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 3;
      right:15px;
    }
    .pic{
      width:100%;
    }
```